# How can i get the link in the href tag from specific element

Tags: xpath, html-agility-pack

I'm trying to get some data from gearbest and I'm having some problems.
Anyway here is the code:

```
var html = @"https://www.gearbest.com/";    
HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();    
var htmlDoc = web.Load(html);    
var nodes = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("/html/body/div[1]/div/ul[2]/li[1]/ul/li//a/span");    
foreach (HtmlNode n in nodes)
{
    Console.WriteLine(n.InnerText);
}
```

Now the program is working and everything is all right, I'm getting the categories list from the `<span>` elements, but I also need to save the link of each one of them.
How can I do that?

Comment: Did you mean the `href` attribute of the `a` parent element? That would be `../@href` with XPath.

Comment: yes, but it gives me the same result, for example, <a href="example.com">Hello</a> ..
i get the "hello", i need the link example.com, how can i do that ?

Comment: and when i try n.attributes it prints this : HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlAttributeCollection

Comment: You need the parent's attribute. Thus you need to perform another selection (by the means of `SelectNodes()`, i.e.) or trasverse the tree through the DOM API

Comment: Never mind it worked, thank you sir !